# Why are 3 dots used as shorthand for “therefore” in maths?

Tags: notation, soft-question

When writing mathematical proof we will commonly use 3 dots in a triangular arrangement as shorthand for therefore.
Is there a reason this symbol is used or was it just decided my someone a long time ago?

P.s. I wasn’t sure what tags to add as it isn’t really about any specific topic

Comment: The Wikipedia article has some of the history (apparently it dates back to a 17th century German text): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Therefore_sign
But also, I wouldn't say it's "common"—I've seen it used as shorthand in a few introductory logic textbooks, and rarely on a blackboard, but almost never in formal writing.

Comment: This is really an [HSM.se](https://hsm.stackexchange.com) question. [_Wikipedia_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Therefore_sign#History) has done some digging (edit: @DanielHast beat me to it). The symbols $\therefore,\,\because$, nowadays meaning _therefore_ and _because_, have at times been used the other way round too for centuries, and [Johann Rahn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Johann_Rahn) is credited with using $\therefore$ first, but I don't know why he made it look that way.

Comment: I don't think it has ever been used in french mathematics literature.

Comment: There is a website that lists the history and first occurrence of practically every math symbol. I think you would enjoy it.

Comment: Hmm, I can't find it now. Maybe someone else knows where it is.

Comment: @JonathanZsupportsMonicaC this site? https://mathshistory.st-andrews.ac.uk/Miller/mathword/

Comment: @DanielHast - I think that's the domain, though symbols are in a different "[section](https://mathshistory.st-andrews.ac.uk/Miller/mathsym/)". I remember it being as unpolished as that. That said, a lot of its info is taken from the Florian Cajori book, so that's another resource.

Comment: AFAIK, this notation is never used in professional math papers.